# Connection refused error when connecting to Kong on Debian

Tags: curl, kong

I run konghq from the [offical Kong Debian Installation instructions](https://docs.konghq.com/install/debian/?_ga=2.155252344.2113249446.1538806145-359804514.1537784236).

But, when I run:

`curl -i http://arzesh:8001/`

I get:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to arzesh port 8001: Connection refused

This is my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   arzesh localhost.localdomain arzesh
127.0.0.1   domain1.local
127.0.1.1   arzesh
#192.168.1.110  gitlabreg.local
#127.0.0.1  192.168.1.6
127.0.0.1   drfactory.local
127.0.0.1   laravel-ci.local
127.0.0.1   latest.local
127.0.0.1   ahf.local

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     arzesh ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Now, I run this command:

`curl -I 'arzesh'`

and I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Sat, 06 Oct 2018 08:37:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Thu, 04 Oct 2018 09:39:44 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5bb5dfe0-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

without any problem!

All ports such as `8080`, `22`, and `80` are working on the server. I run Kong with the default port (8001).

All firewalls (`ufw`,`firewalld`,`iptable`) are disabled.

How I can solve the connection refused error?

Comment: lol :| 
I run the following command: `netstat-tulpn | grep 8001`
And I noticed that the Kong has not started.

Comment: Improved formatting, grammar and rephrased question.